# Select distinct values with Xpath

Tags: xpath

Im using this Xpath query
`//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')]` and the result of this query is:

```
Park
Saga Tokey
Latvia
Latvia
Skande
Paramount
Paramount
Paramount
Oslo
Oslo
...
```

I have been searching and i have come to conclusion that there is a option to select unique or distinct nodevalues/items with Xpath. But i can't get it to work.

I have managede to be able to select specific item with `//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')][1]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')]` (Park in this case), and i thought `//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')][distinct-values()]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')]` would work, but not.

**My question:**
How would my query be to reproduce:

```
Park
Saga Tokey
Latvia
Skande
Paramount
Oslo
...
```

Edit: pastabin with sample
http://pastebin.com/a3x7hRFu

Comment: first, you should show your XML. it is impossible to understand your xpath without that !

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina sorry about that, http://pastebin.com/a3x7hRFu

Comment: First problem: it is not xml, but html. xml parser stops inside. Could you extract an xml part ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina no I don't think i can extract XML. only HTML

Comment: then it is more difficult: you have to clean your html before: with jsoup, html or tagsoup for example: see this:   http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/ , or http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php

Comment: do the repeating values always occur sequentially? from your question and pastebin, it looks like they do, but can it be relied on? I ask because it will affect possible solutions :)

Comment: @KeithHall yes i believe it will always occur sequentially =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 1.0 solution (where there is no `distinct-values` function) that relies on the duplicates being sequential:

`//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre') and (not(../preceding-sibling::li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]) or ../preceding-sibling::li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')][1]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')]/text() != ./text())]`

---

- find all `li` nodes that contain the `cmil_header` class: `//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]`

  - find the child `span` nodes that contain the `cmil_theatre` class: `/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre') and`

    - where there is no previous `li` node containing the `cmil_header` class: `(not(../preceding-sibling::li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')])`
    - *or* the previous `li` node containing the `cmil_header` class has a `span` node child that contains the `cmil_theatre` class: `or ../preceding-sibling::li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')][1]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')]`

      - and the text content of that `span` is not the same as the text content of... : `/text() !=`
  - ...this `span`: `./text())]`

Comment: Veur impressive sir! You've earned a Christmas gift this year! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> i thought //li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')][distinct-values()]/span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')] would work, but not.

No, there is no way this could work. I find it hard to know what you were imagining. The most basic error is that distinct-values() expects an argument. More subtly, you really don't seem to have understood how predicates (expressions in square brackets) work.

What would work -- assuming your XPath processor supports XPath 2.0 -- is

`distinct-values(//li[contains(@class, 'cmil_header')]/
   span[contains(@class, 'cmil_theatre')])`

Comment: I welcome constructive criticism. Downvotes with no comment or explanation achieve nothing.